# Rotating Binary Blackhole Double (Kerr) Solution Approximation

Tags: general-relativity, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance, binary-stars

> As a continuation of my previous inquiry, since the Kerr spacetime metric $$ds^2=-c^2d\tau^2=-\left(1-\frac{r_sr}{\Sigma}\right)c^2dt^2+\frac{\Sigma}{\Delta}dr^2+\Sigma d\theta^2+\left(r^2+a^2+\frac{r_sra^2}{\Sigma}sin^2\theta\right)sin^2\theta d\phi^2-\frac{2r_sra sin^2\theta}{\Sigma}cdtd\phi$$ is the axially symmetric solution of the Einstein field equations for a mass $M$ of angular momentum $J$, for $a=\frac{J}{Mc},$ $\Sigma=r^2+a^2cos^2\theta,$ and $\Delta=r^2-r_sr+a^2,$ in local Boyer–Lindquist coordinates $(x^0,x^1,x^2,x^3)=(ct,r,\theta,\phi),$ how does one *numerically approximate* the metric tensor that corresponds to the spacetime $(M,\mathcal{O},\mathcal{A},g)$ of a system of interacting, rotating binary blackholes with respective angular momenta of $J_1$ and $J_2$? Furthermore, what is the action associated with such a system?

*Attempt:* The localized Lagrangian describing this system may be given (invoking a $O(2)$ gauge theory) as $\mathcal{L}_{loc}=\frac{1}{2}(\nabla_{\mu}\Phi)^T\nabla^{\mu}\Phi-\frac{1}{2}m^Tm\Phi^T\Phi$ where $\nabla_{\mu} =\partial_{\mu}+igA_{\mu}$ is the metric-induced Levi-Civita connection (with $g$ the field coupling constant and $A(x)$ the guage field), $\Phi:=(Tr[G^{\mu \nu}g_{\mu \nu}]_1,Tr[G^{\mu \nu}g_{\mu \nu}]_2)^T$ is the vector of fields for $\phi_i=Tr[G^{\mu \nu}g_{\mu \nu}]_i$ the gravitational scalar field associated with the $i$-th blackhole body, and $m=(M_1,M_2)^T$ is the vector of masses of the respective blackholes. (Unfortunately, this assumes that the metric describing the entire Lorentzian spacetime can be obtained linearly from individual Schwarzchild metrics of the binary in question, which is, of course, not true.) The Lagrangian thereby has local $O(2)$ guage group-invariance, preserved under the transformation $\Phi\mapsto\Phi'=G\Phi$ for $G\in O(2)$ a function of spacetime (i.e. $G:=G(\bf x)$), since the covariant derivative transforms identically as $\nabla_{\mu}\Phi\mapsto (\nabla_{\mu}\Phi)'=G(\nabla_{\mu}\Phi).$

I am using Sean Carroll's *Spacetime and Geometry*; however, the section on binary pulsars does not go into much detail. Please note that I am still very new to this site, so constructive criticism is very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *since the Kerr spacetime metric <...> is the maximally spherically symmetric solution* -- Huh? Kerr solution is *axially* symmetric.

Comment: Sorry, I originally wrote about the Schwarzschild metric and forgot to change it. @A.V.S.